# Game Of Life implemented with for-loops and a boolean-array

Tags: java, game-of-life

> ***There's a Follow-up:*** [Game Of Life rewritten into two classes, PetriDish and Cell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6664/game-of-life-rewritten-into-two-classes-petridish-and-cell)

I wrote an implementation of the [Game Of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) using the easiest approach, a bunch of loops and a boolean array. Yet I feel like I missed something very elemental.

The basic implementation is:

- Check the old generation with loops
- Check each neighbor of each cell...with loops
- Set the status in the generation
- Copy the new generation over the old one

This seems to have some serious downsides, especially the heavy use of loops which makes me a little bit itchy.

```
private boolean[] cells; // Will be set at construction
private int width;
private int height;

/**
 * Evolve into the next nextGeneration.
 */
private void doGeneration() {
    boolean[] nextGeneration = new boolean[cells.length];

    for (int x = 1; x < width - 1; x++) {
        for (int y = 1; y < height - 1; y++) {
            int neighbors = 0;

            // Check surrounding cells.
            for (int neighborX = x - 1; neighborX <= x + 1; neighborX++) {
                for (int neighborY = y - 1; neighborY <= y + 1; neighborY++) {
                    if (neighborX != x || neighborY != y) {
                        if (cells[neighborX * width + neighborY]) {
                            neighbors++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            int idx = x * width + y;

            switch (neighbors) {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                    nextGeneration[idx] = false;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    nextGeneration[idx] = cells[idx];
                    break;

                case 3:
                    nextGeneration[idx] = true;
                    break;

                default:
                    nextGeneration[idx] = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    cells = nextGeneration;
}
```

**Edit:** The whole application ([Slick](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/) dependent for input and drawing) [can be found at GitHub](https://github.com/RobertZenz/Garbagecan/tree/master/slick/GameOfLife).

**Edit2:** There's a bug in the above code. The index should of course be `y * width + x`. I stumbled against that yesterday when I tried to handle non-square grids, but I just realized what was wrong some minutes ago while riding the bus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start it with a `Cell` and a `Grid` class and probably a two-dimensional `Cell` array field in the `Grid`.  `Cell` provides type-safety and more readable code while  probably contains only a `boolean` flag.

Anyway, this implementation can be improved. I'd extract out a `List<Integer> getSurroundingCells(int cellIndex)` and an `int countLiveCells(final List<Integer> cellIndexes)` method. A `boolean getNextValue(int cellIndex, boolean oldValue, int liveNeighborCount)` also could help.

Comment: While I hesitated to write classes for it, you're right. Thinking about it I came to the conclusion that it would ease things in the end, f.e. handling of neighbors and the new generation. I'll do that next.