# Game Of Life rewritten into two classes, PetriDish and Cell

Tags: java, game-of-life

> ***Follow-up to:*** [Game Of Life implemented with for-loops and a boolean-array](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6573/game-of-life-implemented-with-for-loops-and-a-boolean-array)

As proposed by [palacsint](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/7076/palacsint) I went on and rewrote my implementation of the [Game Of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) and extracted everything into two classes:

- **PetriDish**

  - The parent which holds the array of cells
  - Sets the array up and initializes each cell
  - Starts the evolution
- **Cell**

  - Stores it's current value
  - Holds references to it's neighbors

The main cell array is still one-dimensional because I find it convenient to access all cells easily with a simple foreach loop. The outermost cells are a dead border and never change there state, mostly to ease handling of the array.

It works like this:

- Initiate the PetriDish
- Set the array
- Add cells into the array
- Initialize all cells

  - The cell fetches it's neighbors from the parent PetriDish, except if it is a border-cell, then it does nothing.
- The PetriDish kicks off the evolution

  - The cell checks it's neighbors via two static methods, `countAliveNeighbors` and `checkSurvival`
  - It stores that value in a second variable
- The PetriDish ends the evolution

  - The cell overrides it's old value with the new one from the above cycle

This has a few ugly quirks:

- Handling of the border-cells feels a little bit odd, but while I think about it I could remove them completely
- It's necessary to save the new value of the cell in another variable, there for makes the evolution a two-step process

Okay, enough talk, here's the code:

```
public class PetriDish {

    private Cell[] cells;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private long generation;
    private long duration;

    public Cell[] getCells() {
        return cells;
    }

    public Cell getCell(int x, int y) {
        return cells[y * width + x];
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public long getGeneration() {
        return generation;
    }

    public long getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public PetriDish(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        this.cells = new Cell[width * height];

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                cells[y * width + x] = new Cell(this, x, y,
                        x == 0 || y == 0 || x == width - 1 || y == height - 1);
            }
        }

        for (Cell cell : cells) {
            cell.prepare();
        }
    }

    public void doEvolution() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (Cell cell : cells) {
            cell.startEvolution();
        }
        for (Cell cell : cells) {
            cell.finishEvolution();
        }

        generation++;
        duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Cell {

    private PetriDish parent;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private boolean value;
    private boolean nextValue;
    private boolean isBorderCell;
    private List<Cell> neighbors;

    public boolean getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(boolean value) {
        if (!isBorderCell) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public Cell(PetriDish parent, int x, int y, boolean isBorderCell) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        this.isBorderCell = isBorderCell;
        this.neighbors = new ArrayList<Cell>();
    }

    public void prepare() {
        if (!isBorderCell) {
            for (int neighborX = x - 1; neighborX <= x + 1; neighborX++) {
                for (int neighborY = y - 1; neighborY <= y + 1; neighborY++) {
                    if (neighborX != x || neighborY != y) {
                        neighbors.add(parent.getCell(neighborX, neighborY));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void startEvolution() {
        nextValue = checkSurvival(value, countAliveNeighbors(neighbors));
    }

    public void finishEvolution() {
        value = nextValue;
    }

    private static int countAliveNeighbors(Iterable<Cell> neighbors) {
        int neighborsAlive = 0;

        for (Cell neighbor : neighbors) {
            if (neighbor.value) {
                neighborsAlive++;
            }
        }

        return neighborsAlive;
    }

    private static boolean checkSurvival(boolean isAlive, int neighborsAlive) {
        switch (neighborsAlive) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
                return false;

            case 2:
                return isAlive;

            case 3:
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The project can be found [at GitHub](https://github.com/RobertZenz/Garbagecan/tree/master/slick/GameOfLife2) and needs [Slick](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/) for visualization and input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Getter-setter methods in `PetriDish` and `Cell` should be declared after the constructors. (Check [Java Coding Conventions, 3.1.3 Class and Interface Declarations](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-141855.html#1852).) I prefer placing them at the end of the classes (after every other methods).
2. I'd check the input values:

   ```
   import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.*;
   ...

   public PetriDish(final int width, final int height) {
       checkArgument(width > 3, "width has to be at least 3");
       checkArgument(height > 3, "height has to be at least 3");
       ...
   }
   ```

   Of course a simple `if` and a `throw new IllegalArgumentException` also does it if you don't want to include [guava-libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).
3. Passing `this` to another method/class in the constructor usually isn't a good idea:

   ```
   cells[y * width + x] = new Cell(this, x, y, x == 0 || y == 0 
       || x == width - 1 || y == height - 1);
   ```

   If the constructor later throws an exception the created `Cell` objects has a reference to an incompletely constructed `PetriDish` object. (Maybe `Cell` stores the reference in a static field, passes it to an event listener or a singleton class etc.) I'm not sure, but probably I'd create an `init()` method for this logic.
4. Reading the following constructor call isn't the easiest task:

   ```
   new Cell(this, x, y, x == 0 || y == 0 || x == width - 1 || y == height - 1);
   ```

   I'd create a local variable for the last parameter:

   ```
   final boolean isBorderCell = x == 0 || y == 0 || x == width - 1 
       || y == height - 1;
   cells[y * width + x] = new Cell(this, x, y, isBorderCell);
   ```

   An `isBorderCell` method would be the best:

   ```
   private boolean isBorderCell(final int width, final int height, final int x, 
           final int y) {
       if (x == 0) {
           return true;
       }
       if (y == 0) {
           return true;
       }
       if (x == width - 1) {
           return true;
       }
       if (y == height - 1) {
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }
   ```

   I think it's easier to read than a long boolean expression.
5. I'd rename `Cell.prepare()` to `init()`. It's more common.
6. The `prepare` method could be in the `PetriDish` class and could call a `Cell.setNeighbors()`. If you move it `Cell` doesn't have to have `PetriDish` field and constructor parameter at all.
7. `countAliveNeighbors` should be non-static and should use the `neighbors` field directly:

   ```
   private int countAliveNeighbors() {
       ...
   }
   ```

   The same is true for the `checkSurvival` method. Actually, I'd rename it to `calcNextState`:

   ```
   private boolean calcNextState() {
       final int neighborsAlive = countAliveNeighbors();
       switch (neighborsAlive) {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```
8. Use getters instead of direct field access in the `countAliveNeighbors` method:

   ```
   if (neighbor.getValue()) {
       neighborsAlive++;
   }
   ```

   ([What's the deal with Java's public fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7959129/843804))
9. Instead of the `boolean value` flag I'd use an `enum` with `ALIVE` and `DEAD` values. It would be more meaningful (without `true` and `false` as magic "numbers").
10. The `isBorderCell` flag in `Cell` does not smell good. Create a `Cell` interface:

    ```
    public interface Cell {
        void prepare();
        void startEvolution();
        void finishEvolution();
        boolean getValue();
        void setValue(final boolean value);
    }
    ```

    and rename the current `Cell` to `NormalCell` and create an empty `BorderCell` class:

    ```
    public class BorderCell implements Cell {

        @Override
        public void prepare() {
        }

        @Override
        public void startEvolution() {
        }

        @Override
        public void finishEvolution() {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getValue() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValue(boolean value) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }
    ```

    A factory method is useful in the `PetriDish`:

    ```
    private Cell createCell(int x, int y) {
        if (isBorderCell(width, height, x, y)) {
            return new BorderCell();
        } else  {
            return new NormalCell(this, x, y);
        }
    }
    ```

    After that remove the `borderCell` flag and its usages from the `NormalCell` class. (Check *Replacing the Conditional Logic on Price Code with Polymorphism* in *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code* by Martin Fowler)
11. If you would like to get rid of the `nextValue` field in `Cell` try modifying the `doEvolution` method. It could return a new `PetriDish` with brand new `Cell`s which contain the state of the next generation. It would help storing the full history (for example in a `List<PetriDish>`), but I think the current design with the `nextValue` field also fine (if you don't need the full history of course).

Comment: Very nice, thank you, very good recommendations. After some thinking I've decided to drop the border-cells completely and instead just check the values in `prepare()/init()`, the check of the neighbors is done in a foreach anyway, so it won't effect that part, but it will remove a lot of overhead.